# What is a "Tunable Load Generation Front End"?

Tags: load, frontend, agile

I recently got an internship for the summer. My job summary is as follows:

> Job Summary:  Selected Intern will design, code and test a Tunable
>   Load Generation Front End to control volume operations, snapshots, 
>   etc. based on a CPU Load % / Disk Load % specified by the user. This 
>   tool will make use of existing load generation tools.    Essential
>   Functions:
>
> - Agile software development
> - Object-Oriented Design using Python language
> - Creation of User Documentation
> - Operating Systems knowledge

Can anyone explain to me what a "Tunable Load Generation Front End" is?  I am currently studying agile software programming/development, so info on that is appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very broad term and could mean different things to different people.

The core problem is that applications behave much differently under load than under normal test conditions.  Most teams use some sort of tool to load test their software before putting it into production.  This tool generates some load (for web applications it will usually be many, many HTTP requests) and report on the performance characteristics of the application.

The most difficult part of this process to get right is to get a load profile that more or less mirrors your production load.  Then there are also questions of how the application will perform under future (increased) load.  Or what might happen if traffic is directed to different parts of the site.

My interpretation of a "Tunable Load Generation Front End" is a tool that you can use to change the parameters of your load test.  You can then choose parameters to mimic your production load, or perhaps setup tests to test your software under other anticipated scenarios, with minimal effort.